# Заменить переменную при наличии в URL страницы значения?

Tags: php

При наличии в адресе страницы "v_nalichii" нужно заменить адрес ссылки в навигации. Но на выводе выводимая переменная не меняется, в чем ошибка сравнения?

```
    <?php $getUrl = $APPLICATION->GetCurPage();
                    $linkAvail = "v_nalichii/";
        ?>
        <?php if (strpos($getUrl, $linkAvail)):?>
            <?php $linkAvail = "";?>
            <?=$linkAvail?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <li class="filter-item">
            <a href="<?=$linkAvail?>" class="link-avail"><input type="checkbox" class="filter-avail" name="filter" value="avail"></a>
            <label class="name" for="avail"><a href="v_nalichii/" class="link-avail">В наличии</a></label>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать код, таким образом, чтобы вы видели что у вас находится в переменных, тогда, я думаю вы поймете в чем проблема:

```html
<? $getUrl = $APPLICATION->GetCurPage(); var_dump($getUrl); // а давайте проверим что к нам пришло? ?>
<? $linkAvail = "v_nalichii/"; ?>

<? $checker = strpos($getUrl, $linkAvail); var_dump($checker); // удалось ли найти совпадения в строке? ?>

<? if ($checker): ?>
  <? $linkAvail = ""; ?>
<? endif; ?>

<li class="filter-item">
  <a href="<?= $linkAvail ?>" class="link-avail">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-avail" name="filter" value="avail"></a>
    <label class="name" for="avail">
      <a href="v_nalichii/" class="link-avail">В наличии</a>
    </label>
</li>
```